# Send automatic message to live chat after the successful payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I'm building e-commerce website with Woocommerce. I want to get a message in the live chat with payment details once customer completes his order(after successful payment). I've been googling a lot and I couldn't find any information except 'hooks'. Is that how it's done? With hooks? Or maybe there is a plugin for that?